# git - terminal window - imac - diff can not type any more

Tags: git, github

```
diff --git a/hellokitdoc.rtf b/hellokitdoc.rtf

    index e906e3b..703dd99 100644
    --- a/hellokitdoc.rtf
    +++ b/hellokitdoc.rtf
    @@ -4,4 +4,6 @@
     \margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
     \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx79

    -\f0\fs24 \cf0 my hello kit doc starts there}
    \ No newline at end of file
    +\f0\fs24 \cf0 this is newly updated line.\
    +\
    +}
    \ No newline at end of file
    (END)
```

After the (END) the very last line.. I can not type any more in the terminal window.. I have to close the terminal window and navigate back in and then issue commands all over. Why is that??

Answer (score 3):

Just press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key to exit the pager. Use the <kbd>H</kbd> key to get some help. Using <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> you can scroll up and down one line at a time. <kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> do the same, but half-a-screen at the time. <kbd>/</kbd>+`string`+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> searches forward for `string`, while <kbd>?</kbd>+`string`+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> searches backwards. `string` can also be a regular expression. <kbd>G</kbd> scrolls to the top, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to the bottom. Those are the most important commands I use, but there are many more, refer to the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/less.1.html).